# Geocoding alternatives to rmapzen

Tags: r, geocoding, mapbox, mapzen

I think you know that the **Mapzen** service has closed. Unfortunately I'm on several projects based on R and Mapzen APIs, so I was looking for alternative services for which a package or a series of R functions were available (especially for geocoding). 
Some geocoding packages I already considered:

- **opencage**: I don't like the pricing and the provided features
- **tmaptools**: there is a nice function, geocode_OSM, but since it uses OSM Nominatim servers after a certain amount of requests (i think ~2000) it is rate limited.
- **ggmap**: I wouldn't use it since it uses Google services.

I think the best offer it's the **Mapbox** one (a lot of free requests and pay as you use) but i didn't find a r package for it yet.

Which other geocoding packages I should consider? (apart self hosting)

Comment: Check the mapzen offical post for Mapzen Alternatives https://mapzen.com/blog/migration/

Comment: i did it. The alternatives of that doc are described in my question

Comment: For software recommendations there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Our [GraphHopper Geocoding](https://graphhopper.com/api/1/docs/geocoding/) solution also comes with an (untested) R client: https://github.com/graphhopper/directions-api-clients

Comment: Mapzen is evolving to geocode.earth, see also https://geocode.xyz